# merging(concatenation of) output of the network with the input it receives in keras custom models creates error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

im trying to implement a jordan net with some Dense layers , i want to merge the output of the net with input (i want the network to see its k last predicted values, but right now getting it to work with just last value suffices). im using custom model in keras 2. ive tried everything but the there is error on merge(layer) no matter that i use tf.concat or tf.keras.layers.concatenation  . the model may compile but it will not train or predict.

error is --->    AttributeError: 'Concatenate' object has no attribute 'shape'

```
class Jordan (tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self,num_feedback=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.feedback = np.zeros((1,num_feedback))
        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')
        self.outp = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputss):
        _concat = tf.concat ( [  self.feedback , inputss ] )
        _1 = self.l1(_concat)
        _2 = self.l2(_1)
        _output = self.outp(_2)
        self.feedback = _output
        return _output

a = np.ones((100,6))
b = np.ones((100,1))
model = jordan(10)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='MSE',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(a,b,epochs=10)
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: AttributeError: 'Concatenate' object has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score 0):

ok here was the problem , in model.fit()  you need to adjust the bach_size to the first dimension of the self.feedback -------> it is 1 at this code so the batch size shall be 1.